# EQS is not available?

Tags: unreal-engine4

- Unreal Engine 4.18.3,
- Windows 10,
- C++ or Blueprints,
- Top Down or Third Person Project.

I'm really sorry - I can't add an Environmental Query. It's not available in the AI menu when trying to "Add New" to add an advanced item, it's not in project settings, and you can't add one from the BT.

I can't follow the AI tutorial as there's no way to add an EQS query. I've looked in many posts and other forums but nothing seems to apply to 4.18.3

Also, I can't find any ini file setting with anything like "EnvironmentQuery" in it, to enable it in some ini file.

Is there some add-on I need to install?
How can I add an Environment Query to my project?

---

#### Solved

In Config/DefaultEngine.ini I had to manually add:

```
[EnvironmentQueryEd]
EnableEnvironmentQueryEd=True
```

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**
In Config/DefaultEngine.ini I had to manually add:

```
[EnvironmentQueryEd] EnableEnvironmentQueryEd=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Environment Query System:

1. Edit Menu -> Editor Preferences
2. Experimental
3. Scroll down to AI
4. Enable Environment Query System

[image: Enabling the Environment Query System]

Comment: This option was not available in the version I was having trouble with.